Hide or disable background/atmosphere on Mapbox GL
I am working on a project with Mapbox GL to display maps. I want to hide/disable the atmosphere like "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11" style.
I've tried modifying the map style and setting the background color to transparent, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
The default style "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11" has transaprent background. But I cant make my own style like that. :(
There are several answers on stackoverflow, but all of them doesdo not work. Here
like this 


I was able to get it working.
It seems like setting atmosphere -> OFF doesn't instantly remove it for some reason.
However, you can set it ON and edit the atmosphere values to create a transparent atmosphere, which essentially provides the same effect.

